# Enabling SCIM in Azure for non premium License holder

Tags: azure, api, scim

Does Azure Admin need to hold a premium license to enable SCIM? Are existing gallery Apps pre-enabled for SCIM?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use DataBricks in Azure AD enterprise apps gallery in order to test your SCIM service:
In Azure -> Active Directory -> Enterprise Apps menu -> new app -> Azure Databricks SCIM Provisioning Connector.
However, you can't edit attribute maps in it.